# PyCharm doesn't let me add remote interpreter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I have problem with docker compose remote interpreter in PyChart. I'm using docker compose v2, PyCharm 2021.2.3 and macOS Monterey version 12.0.1.

```sh
docker compose version
# Docker Compose version v2.1.1
```

When I want to add new remote interpreter, I always got same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDIpW.png) `config.registryAddress must not be null`. Googling shows that it can be local docker registry, but I don't have any, only private on cloud and I'm logged in there. I can pull images and all that stuff. I've tried `docker compose up` in terminal and it works as usual. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly same for me. I'm working on Mac with a remote docker host via ssh. Docker itself works fine, but not in PyCharm. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284570 for updates.

Comment: @artem, hi, sorry maybe I'm late. I solved this problem by logging out from the docker registry via CLI. Then I reinstall docker desktop.